QUdpSocket readyRead never emitted
I want to read incoming udp datagram on port 55001. I run the following code but read is never called.
I see "Bind success" on console so no problem on bind
I have verified that I can see the incoming udp datagrams on port 55001 using wireshark.
I don't have any clue why I cannot read the udp messages. Any help is welcome
class MyCls : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QUdpSocket* UdpSocketPtr;

    MyCls()
    {
        UdpSocketPtr = new QUdpSocket(this);
        bool result = UdpSocketPtr->bind(QHostAddress::Any, 55001);
        if (result == true)
        {
            qDebug() << "Bind success";
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << "Bind fail";
        }
        connect(UdpSocketPtr, &QUdpSocket::readyRead, this, &MyCls::read);
    }
    
public slots:
    void read()
    {
        qDebug() << "read called";
        QByteArray datagram;
        QHostAddress senderAddr;
        quint16 senderPort;

        while (UdpSocketPtr->hasPendingDatagrams())
        {
            datagram.resize(UdpSocketPtr->pendingDatagramSize());

            UdpSocketPtr->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(), &senderAddr, &senderPort);
            qDebug() << "Message: " << datagram.data();
        }
    }
}

I have seen on some questions, people added Qt::QueuedConnection as 5th parameter to connect. Tried that too but no success.
I have seen on a answer that sometimes a datagram is stuck (?) in memory and that is why readyRead is never emitted again. To fix that that answer added another call to readDatagram after the while loop. Tried that as well but no success.
Edit: I changed the code a bit to check whether data is coming at all. I repeatedly call readDatagram 10000 times on read and i called read at the end of constructor. I have seen data is coming. So problem is not there, it is just that readyRead signal is not emitted

In order to receive the sent data in your slot, the receiving thread needs to be free so that event loop finds the time to process messages.
You are probably creating your udp socket object on the main thread and at the same time you are keeping your main thread busy. Make a QThread and move your udp socket object to it using moveToThread member function of your socket.

Yes i was using the main gui thread to listen, moving it to different thread solved the issue thank you

Or simply use signals and slots instead creating a seaprate thread for such a simple task.

@chehrlic Provided example uses signal\slot. Signal\slots aren't asynchronic, so it quite possible to miss, if emitter is created from a thread which doesn't have message  loop or if its message loop is busy.

You won't miss any signal/slot connection. Don't use threads for a simple QUdpSocket - it's not needed and just makes headaches (as proven here).

@chehrlic Not sure what you mean "as proven here". you get two edge cases there: program performs long task or doesn't enter message loop and socket device wouldn't fire event. It's likely what was going on. not all Qt programs have GUI (and it means another problem is there) You also may end with deadlock, if qDebug is outputting to something controlled by UI. Or, you will receive datagrams so often that it would block UI (on Windows it is a catastrophe).
